# Customize map to display on mkmapview

Tags: dictionary, mkmapview, customization

Would anyone know if it is possible to display a different map than the standard one on mapKit (like climates for instance) ? Can we do that with pictures and overlays ? Do you know where I could get some maps that fit for that ?
Great thanks.

Benja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with geotif images  like so  [How to accurately make a map for a map-overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309670/how-to-accurately-make-a-map-for-a-map-overlay/6318361#6318361)

Comment: That seems to be what I am looking for ! Thanks a lot Craig !